# How can I determine the "alternate access control method" when the access flags in ls end with a `+`

Tags: linux, ls, acl

On my Ubuntu, the directory in which pluggable media is mounted (`/media/me`) is owned by root and has access flags `drwxr-x---+`, so without the "alternate access control method" indicated by the `+` I wouldn't be able to access it.

How I can I determine which access control method is used and where it is set?

Comment: Try `getfacl /media/me` (`acl` package, see also the `acl` man page). I'm not aware of other methods supported by Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. Now trying to figure out why they used ACLs for this.